# Why Box smallBox = scoped!Box(); is a BUG in D?

Tags: d

In "Programming in D" book "[destroy and scoped](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/destroy.html)" chapter the author writes that one should be careful when using **scoped** as it introduces a bug IF one specifies the actual class type on the left hand side.

```
Box c = scoped!Box();
```

> In that definition, c is not the proxy object; rather, as defined by the programmer, a class variable referencing the encapsulated object. Unfortunately, the proxy object that is constructed on the right-hand side gets terminated at the end of the expression that constructs it. As a result, using c in the program would be an error, likely causing a runtime error.

Such that

```
Box smallBox = scoped!Box(); // BUG!
auto smallBox = scoped!Box(); // works fine
const smallBox = scoped!Box(); // works fine
```

The explanation given is a little bit high level to me because how `auto smallBox` is different from `Box smallBox` except that the type will be inferred by the compiler? What is so different between explicit type specification and D compiler inferring that it allows **scoped** proxy struct to terminate the object ahead of time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, the compiler will try to convert your type on the right to match the type on the left in a declaration. Both sides have a specific type already - the left-hand side will not actually influence code on the right to be a different type - just it will convert. The compiler will try to do as little conversion as possible to match the left, and issue an error if it is impossible.

```
auto a = x;
```

Here, `auto` has no restrictions, so the type of `a` is identical to the type of `x`, thus no conversion is necessary. This is your most basic case of type inference.

```
const a = x;
```

Here, the left-hand side is `const`, but otherwise is unrestricted. Thus, the compiler will try to convert x's type to `const` without further changing it. This is slightly more complex type inference, but still pretty simple.

```
Box a = x;
```

But here, the left-hand side is specifically typed `Box`. So whatever `x` is, the compiler will try to convert it *specifically* to `Box`. This might call upon various user-defined conversions, like `alias this`, inside the right-hand type, or might do implicit conversions too.

Let's get concrete:

```
byte a;
auto x = a; // x is `byte`, just like a
const y = a; // y is now `const(byte)`, applying const to a's type
int z = a; // z is always an int, now a is converted to it.
```

In the case of `z` there, `a` got implicitly converted to `int`. This is allowed, so no error, but `z` and `a` are now different things. You see similar things with base classes and interfaces:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

auto one = new B(); // one is type B
A two = new B(); // two is now of type A, the B object got converted to the base class A
```

With `byte`, `int`, and with classes, this basically works as expected. Bytes and ints are basically the same thing, and classes keep a runtime type tag to remember who they really are.

But with structs, it can lead to some information being lost.

```
struct A {}
struct B { A a; alias a this; }
```

That struct `B` is now implicitly convertable to type `A`... but it does so by just returning an individual member (`a`) while leaving the rest of `B` behind.

```
B b;
A a = b; // the same as `A a = b.a;`, it only keeps that one member in `a`
```

This is what `scoped` does on the inside. It looks something like this:

```
struct Scoped(Class) {
     Class c;
     alias c this;
     ~this() { destroy(c); } // destructor also destroys child object
}
```

That `alias this` magic line allows it to convert back to the Class type... but it does so by only returning that one reference member, while abandoning the rest of `Scoped`, which - by the definition of Scoped's purpose - means it is gone and destroys the Class' memory in the process. Thus you are left with a reference to a destroyed object, which is the bug they are warning about.